# How to create a recursive search with logic in Excel?

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a function in Excel that will search down a column of distance values and flag them based on a specified filter distance. It seems like it will involve logic and a recursive search. I just need a place to get started because I don't have any experience with using either of those in Excel.

For a simple example, if I wanted to keep the points that were located on a 20' interval, the result would look something like the image below. The function would populate the 'filter' column after searching through the 'distance' column.

Here is a link to the actual dataset. The distances are variable. Ideally the function should be scalable so that the filter distance can be any number (filter every 10', 20', 13', etc.): 
[example dataset link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwGyFVg6x3zlVnhERHZqV0p4dXM)

Thanks

[image]

Comment: why not just keep points 1, 2, and 3?

Comment: The points are along a path of travel. I need to filter them down so that there is a new subset that only contains points every 20' in this case.

Comment: ah, I see.  But you'd like to keep point 1 by default?

Comment: It's not that critical to keep point 1; I could manually just add that one later. I've got 4,000 points to filter so the big necessity is just filtering out those points on that 20' interval.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use the MOD function in Excel.  In C2 try:

```
=IF(MOD(SUM($B$2:B2),20)=0,"Keep","")
```

You will need to manually add the first keep.  This worked on your test data and should get you started.  It will bomb if the intervals don't end exactly at 20'.  So if your data is more complex than what you posted, you'll need another solution (and should post more representative data next time).

Comment: My data is more complex. I've edited the question and shared a link to the actual dataset.